# ImageButton not Acting as expected in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, imagebutton

Here is code first:

```
     <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/llReviewView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:background="#d8d9d9"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:background="#fff"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/bWiki"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_weight="90"
                android:background="@drawable/wiki_selector"
                android:contentDescription="Wiki Link"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_info_wiki" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="1px"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#666" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/spinner_bg_selector"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerSort"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:background="@drawable/spinnerselector" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
     // edited
 </LinearLayout>
```

wiki_selector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/row_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>

     <!-- Normal -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wiki_normal" android:state_pressed="false"/>


</selector>
```

Here is image of the view:

[image]

**Here are the problems:**

1. Only pressing the "i" icon in the middle of the image button works.
2. Clicking on the white space does nothing, but does activate the selector - of the Spinner to the right!
3. The wiki_selector does nothing.

Comment: You haven't copied your complete layout in the question.

Comment: With your parent ViewGroup's orientation being android:orientation="vertical", you won't have the above layout in the picture. You need to update that too maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "i" button will only respond when tapped within its bounding rectangle.  I think, since you have width=0dp, it's getting set to its minimum width.

You need to decide what proportions you want the spinner vs the "i" button to occupy.  Also, I'm not sure what purpose you have in mind for the two LinearLayouts.  If it's already showing everything you want, you don't then the LinearLayouts.

Now, let's say you want the spinner to occupy only the width needed for its contents.  Then, you should set its width as WRAP_CONTENT.  For the spinner you would choose MATCH_PARENT and (I'm not sure of this) add layout_weight="1".

Alternatively, if you want the "i" button to occupy 2/3 of the width and the spinner 1/3, you need width for both to be "0dp" and the "i" button should have layout_weight="2", the spinner "1".

Comment: If this answer helped, please upvote. If you feel it's the correct answer, then check it. That will encourage people to answer future questions :)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay.  Though I marked correct, but I didn't.  This helped thanks!